# Segmentation fault (core dumped): scanf int data to array with C

Tags: c, arrays

Are there any limitations when implementing `scanf` int data type to an array in C? The code below gives me a "segmentation fault(core dumped) when array has more than 6 indices.

====example code=========

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
    int size;
    int array[size];
    int x;

    scanf("%d", &size);

    for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
        scanf("%d", &array[x]);
    }
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
        printf("[%d] ", array[x]);
    }
 }


input:
4
3 45 5 76
output:
[3] [45] [5] [76]

input:
7
34 2 5 6 9 3 8
output:
Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

My goal is to have a dynamic array. The user will decide its size. So far this proves impossible. I understand the dynamic array approach can be implemented with `struct` or c++ `vector`. However, I would like to understand whether the error is due to the code structure or am I ignorant of certain limitation in the C array.

I look forward to your knowledgeable input.

Comment: you array as size 0, because the size is 0 at compile time. To change de size of the array at run time you have to allocate memory for the array using malloc. Don't forget to free memory at the end

Comment: At the time you declare `array[size]`, `size` is uninitialized. Changing `size` afterwards is too late!

Comment: ...and whether `size` is initialized **after** the `scanf()` is unclear, since **you did not check the return value**. If the user entered letters instead of digits, `scanf( "%d", &size )` will fail, leaving `size` uninitialized (and all subsequent `scanf( "%d", ... )` will fail as well as the letters are still sitting in `stdin`, unread).

Comment: 1. Your `size` is a random number off the stack, thus your `array[size]` is of an unknown size at runtime. 2. You don't `malloc()` any memory to ensure it has enough memory to fit there, and be a dynamic array. 3. Use a hardcoded known value, such as `array[128]` instead of `array[size]` until you switch to using a dynamicly-allocated array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to point out 2 things

1. Write int array[size]; after scanf statement and include stdlib.h in your code. In the new versions of gcc compiler takes care of memory allocation and finally freeing it for you. Also return some value as your return type is int.
2. But my advise to you is that use malloc statement in the following fashion as you might need to run the code on older version of gcc. And also compiler internally does the same thing.

   ```
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>
       int main(void)
       {    
           int size;
           scanf("%d", &size);
           int *array;
           array=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
           int x;

           for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
               scanf("%d", &array[x]);
           }
           for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
               printf("[%d] ", array[x]);
           }
     free (array);
     return 0;

    }
   ```

Comment: don't use cast in allocation.

Comment: Why? What's the problem?

Comment: [Don't cast malloc() return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845) in C. (*Do* cast in C++.) **DO** check `scanf()` return value, always.

Comment: For people that don't yet understand why the array size is failing in this case, advising them to use malloc is really doing them a disservice. That said, if you're going to provide an example using `malloc`, don't you think the call to `malloc` should actually be somewhere in the code you provide? Bravo on at least including the `free()` but currently `array` is not properly initialized.

Comment: Thanks Kevin and everyone else. I also realize the importance of `free()` in freeing memory to prevent buffer overflow issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int size;
 int array[size];
```

`size` is uninitialized right now . Array of what size would be created ?

Declare array after `scanf("%d",&size)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `array[size]` when `size` is not defined yet ! Instead if you want to use a dynamic array, you can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{    
  int size;
  int *array;
  int x;

  if (scanf("%d", &size)==1){
  array=calloc(size*sizeof(int));
  }
  //check if allocation has been done      

  for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
    scanf("%d", &array[x]);
  }
  for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
    printf("[%d] ", array[x]);
  }

  free(array);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf()`. *PLEASE.*

Comment: @DevSolar check if it is int or not?

Comment: @DevSolar so should I initialise it or my modification is ok? 
int size=0; ?

Comment: @DevSolar so I changed my allocation to calloc in order to have all equal 0.

Comment: For people that don't yet understand why the array size is failing in this case, advising them to use malloc (or calloc) is really doing them a disservice.

Answer (score 0):

The "classic" way would be to allocate memory for your array, either using `malloc(size * sizeof(int))` or by using `calloc(size, sizeof(int))`. The former makes no guarantees as to the state of the memory allocated (apart from "allocated"), the latter guarantees that the memory has been zeroed before the function returns.

Comment: For people that don't yet understand why the array size is failing in this case, advising them to use malloc is really doing them a disservice.

Answer (score 0):

Better you dynamically allocate memory for taking a user input size.

```
int *arr,size;
scanf("%d",size);
arr=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
```

This will create an integer array of length "size".

Comment: For people that don't yet understand why the array size is failing in this case, advising them to use malloc is really doing them a disservice.